# BoneCP automatic reconnect

Tags: reconnect, bonecp

Does BoneCP have any mechanism (i.e. configuration) that will allow an automatic reconnect to a MySQL database if the database has been taken offline and restarted

Answer (score 0):

Yes - have a look at the transactionReplay feature (but don't use it if you're using Hibernate)